# Rerun a failed workflow in SWF

Tags: amazon-swf

In AWS SWF, if the decider has failed some workflow executions due to SCHEDULE_TO_START timeout in activities, then how can we re-run them both using AWS console and in program? Is there any other solution through which we can handle failures due to such timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

SWF doesn't support rerunning workflow from some activity.

I would recommend setting SCHEDULE_TO_START timeout to a very high value and do not fail workflow. This way you can fix the underlying problem without ever restarting workflows.

You can look into [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source project which is based on SWF ideas. It does support a [reset operation](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/tctl/workflow/reset/) to rerun workflows from any point.